# My if statements don't work the way I expect them to (C#)

Tags: c#, if-statement

I am creating a number-guessing in C#, and I am using `if` statements in it. This is my code:

```cs
namespace number guessing            
{
    class Program
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Welcome to the Number Guessing Game!");
            Console.WriteLine("You have to guess the number the computer has chosen, ranging from 1 to 100.");
            Console.WriteLine("Good Luck!");
            Random gen = new Random(1 - 100);
            int number1 = gen.Next();
            int number2 = gen.Next();
            int userGuess = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            if (userGuess < number1)
            {
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
                Console.WriteLine("Too large! Guess a smaller number!");
                Console.WriteLine("Guess again!");
                Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Black;
            }
            if (userGuess > number1)
            {
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Blue;
                Console.WriteLine("Too small! Guess a larger number!");
                Console.WriteLine("Guess again!");
                Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Black;
            }
            if (userGuess == number1)
            {
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
                Console.WriteLine("Well done! You found the secret number!");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When I run the code, it only shows "Too large! Guess a smaller number!". I do not know how to fix this and Visual Studios also says that there is no error so... I would like help, please.

Note: I don't mind any tips on making this code a little bit more condensed!

Comment: What do you think [`new Random(1 - 100)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.random.-ctor?view=net-6.0#System_Random__ctor_System_Int32_) does?

Comment: Your best friend, the [debugger](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y740d9d3.aspx), should help!

Now is the time to learn it! Really !! Just add a breakpoint at the line .. and step once.. To set a breakpoint click at the grey part to the left of the line number. It will create a dark red circle.. - To step press F11 !

Comment: @GSerg I thought it would generate a number from 1 to 100 because I saw someone else do it like that on YouTube so I tried it  I found it did not work!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This this is the cause of your issue:

```
Random gen = new Random(1 - 100);
```

It is the equivalent of this:

```
Random gen = new Random(-99);
```

Which says to seed the pseudo random number generator with the seed of `-99`. That means that it will always return the same pseudo random numbers each time it runs.

So when you run these lines:

```
int number1 = gen.Next();
int number2 = gen.Next();
```

...you always get the same numbers.

Now, I my computer I get these numbers:

```
958527983
1859223698
```

The reason they are so large is that `Random.Next()` returns a non-negative random integer. So inclusive between the value of `0` and `2147483647`.

If you want to generate a number between `1` and `100` then you need this code:

```
Random gen = new Random();
int number = gen.Next(1, 101);
```

Here's the full code to implement your guessing game:

```
Console.WriteLine("Welcome to the Number Guessing Game!");
Console.WriteLine("You have to guess the number the computer has chosen, ranging from 1 to 100.");
Console.WriteLine("Good Luck!");
Random gen = new Random();
int number = gen.Next(1, 101);
while (true)
{
    int userGuess = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
    if (userGuess > number)
    {
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
        Console.WriteLine("Too large! Guess a smaller number!");
    }
    else if (userGuess < number)
    {
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Blue;
        Console.WriteLine("Too small! Guess a larger number!");
    }
    else
    {
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
        Console.WriteLine("Well done! You found the secret number!");
        break;
    }
    Console.WriteLine("Guess again!");
    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Black;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I've fixed it and now it works! 

Answer (score -2):

```
public static void Main()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Welcome to the Number Guessing Game!");
            Console.WriteLine("You have to guess the number the computer has chosen, ranging from 1 to 100.");
            Console.WriteLine("Good Luck!");
            Random gen = new Random();//dont pass paramter for range here 
            int number1 = gen.Next(1,100);//pass range parameter here  
            //int number2 = gen.Next(1,100);
            int userGuess = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            if (userGuess < number1)
            {
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
                Console.WriteLine("Too small! Guess a larger number!");
                Console.WriteLine("Guess again!");
               userGuess= Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Black;
            }
            if (userGuess > number1)
            {
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Blue;
                Console.WriteLine("Too large! Guess a smaller number!");
                Console.WriteLine("Guess again!");
                userGuess = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Black;
            }
            if (userGuess == number1)
            {
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
                Console.WriteLine("Well done! You found the secret number!");
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Your Attempt is Over..Please REStart Game !");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please update your answer, providing context and why it solves the problem instead of posting a "nude" block of code. I believe that's why your answer has been downvoted.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).